# Login with office 365 using django all-auth

Tags: django, office365, django-allauth

How can I incorporate login with office 365 using django all-auth?
Currently I am using django-allauth to implement Login with facebook, gmail.

I found one tutorial here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/05/office-365-apis-and-python-part-1-oauth2/

on implementing the same, but it has it's own sets of tables that i don't want to use.

Comment: Either code it yourself as another provider http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html or request it in issues: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues